# Dynamic Table Creation in Java with No DB link

Tags: java, database, dynamic, creation

In my Java application I want to create a table whose data field will be updated dynamically. The table is not linked with any database. The tables' data fields are ArrayList or List type data so I want to update the fields when they are changing. I was looking into the jtable but was unable to find the way to do that. Anyone knows the solution is highly appreciated..

Comment: are you working in swings, I mean do you want to display table in UI or want to make a table in memory?

Comment: I like to see in memory if it possible.  I was looking into swings also. In short, the idea is to display the tables as a pop Up window and to have as low as burden to the memory.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do the following

- Create a class for each table
- to create dynamic fields implement a map which stores name of the field as key and its value as the value of the map
- create one object for each row and store them, in List(or map if you want to do indexing)
- Implement search functions
- Update it as and when required.

Jtable is the component for UI, You can easily use it and if there is some problem in displaying the data, you are always welcome to ask.